# what is the code for spec file in protractor to launch native android app on android emulator

Tags: android, automation, android-emulator, protractor, appium

I am able to launch an android emulator using the configuration:

```
capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        platformName: 'Android',
        platformVersion: '7.0',
        deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
        app:'./app-debug.apk'
    },

//baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000',
baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000',
```

But what should be the further steps to actually run the automation code on the native app using emulator??

Answer (score 0):

Protractor **do not support Native apps** testing, only mobile browsers and Hybrid ones (starting with webview)

[Proof](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4259)

If you won't to use **js** and test mobile native app you better check **wd** and **webdriverio** libraries.

Comment: Is everyone sure on this, that protractor doesn't support testing of native apps. Because as per:       https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md             I think this might be feasible...

Comment: It's possible only for Hybrid Apps and moblie browsers - cause protractor is Selenium based library, if you have native app then it's only with appium-based  libraries that support UiAutomator and XCUITEST respectively. So if you have natvive Android/iOS app - protractor won't help you, at least for now

Answer (score -2):

In protractor you can do testing on mobile browser. 
Here is way you can use selenium to do mobile app automation:
***http://learn-automation.com/automate-native-applications-using-appiumselenium/***